# How to properly animate SKSpriteNode subclasses

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I designed a SKSpriteNode subclass `Ship`, and I want to know how to go about animating it with a couple different images. I'm currently passing in an original image with:

```
class Ship:SKSpriteNode{
    static var shipImage = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Sprites/fullShip.png")

        init(startPosition startPos:CGPoint, controllerVector:CGVector){
            super.init(texture: Ship.shipImage, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: Ship.shipImage.size())
```

but I'm not sure how to loop through an image atlas afterwards. I first attempted using a method inside the class that was then called in the `update` function:

```
func animateShip() {
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.animateWithTextures(shipAnimationFrames,
            timePerFrame: 0.2,
            resize: false,
            restore: true)),
            withKey:"shipBlink")

        print("animate")
    }
```

`var shipAnimationFrames : [SKTexture]!` is declared right above `GameScene`, and this block is located in `didMoveToView`

```
    //Ship animation
    let shipAnimatedAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "ShipImages")
    var blinkFrames = [SKTexture]()

    let numImages = shipAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i=1; i<=numImages; i += 1 {
        let shipTextureName = "samShip\(i).png"
        blinkFrames.append(shipAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(shipTextureName))
    }

    shipAnimationFrames = blinkFrames
```

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Texture Atlas

First of all you need to create a texture atlas into `Assets.xcassets`. You'll put here the images related to the frames of your character.

[image]

### Subclassing SKSpriteNode

This is how you create you own sprite with a beginAnimation method

```
class Croc: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "croc_walk01")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    }


    func beginAnimation() {
        let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "croc")
        let frames = ["croc_walk01", "croc_walk02", "croc_walk03", "croc_walk04"].map { textureAtlas.textureNamed($0) }
        let animate = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame: 0.1)
        let forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animate)
        self.runAction(forever)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

As you can see the beginAnimation method creates a texture atlas using the same name of the texture atlas I previously created in `Assets.xcassets`.

Then the an array of textures is created (`frames`) and used as parameter to create the `animate` action.

### Starting the animation

Now you need to create your sprite and invoke `beginAnimation` just once. You do NOT have to invoke beginAnimations inside any update method otherwise you will create a new animation every new frame. The is wrong. beginAnimation must be called only once.

Here's an example

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let croc = Croc()
        croc.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        addChild(croc)

        croc.beginAnimation()
    }
}
```

[image]